# Excel doesnt recognize date from mysql as date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel, date

I have mysql db linked to SQL server. 
On SQL server I am using procedure with DBCC TRACEON(8765) to run mysql query. One of the columns is Date_entered , returning the values in iso format YYYY-MM-DD. Then in Excel I have data connection to run this procedure.
Problem is that Date_entered in Excel, even though it is in the format YYYY-MM-DD is not recognized in Excel as date. The consequence is that I cannot group this field in the pivot table.
I even tried DATE_FORMAT in mysql, but still no luck in Excel.

Anybody has an idea please ?
Thx Petr

Comment: Is the column an actual `DATE` column?  If not, something along the lines of `SELECT CAST(column_name AS DATE) AS column_name` would probably be what you want.  `DATE_FORMAT` is not what you want, since its return value is a character string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Excel is seeing the value as a text string. It's possible that leading white space is causing excel to not recognize the date. Create a new column and use the trim() function to remove the and leading/trailing spaces, they try to reformat the date.

Alternatively you could just brute force it and parse the string for the year, month, and day. Assuming the date is always in the format you've specified: YYYY-MM-DD, try this:

```
=DATE(LEFT(TRIM(A1),4),MID(TRIM(A1),6,2),RIGHT(TRIM(A1),2))
```

*(this assumes your date is in cell a1)*

Answer (score 0):

You could add a columns and use the formula =value() and assign it to the Date_entered column

Answer (score 0):

Below mysql query might help:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date('2014-10-24','%Y-%m-%d'), '%m/%d/%Y') as FormattedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved my problem by modifying the procedure on SQL server to:

```
BEGIN
DBCC TRACEON(8765);
SELECT *,CAST(CAST(year(calldate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(month(calldate) AS    varchar) + '-' + CAST(day(calldate) AS varchar) AS DATETIME) as calldate2, datename(dw,calldate) as den

FROM OPENQUERY(SugarCRM, 'SELECT * FROM crm.acm_ivr' );
END;
```

This particular part of the code "converts" the mysql date `calldate` to date recognizable by MS Excel `calldate2`:

```
CAST(CAST(year(calldate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(month(calldate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(day(calldate) AS varchar) AS DATETIME) as calldate2
```